# installing node.js typescript packages on vs2017

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, typescript

I'm trying to write a node.js server with typescript.

I found this link which explains how to do it:
http://brianflove.com/2016/03/29/typescript-express-node-js/

They install the typescript versions of "body-parser", "express", etc, but they do it from the console like so:

```
node_modules/.bin/typings install body-parser --ambient --save
```

Is there a way to do it with visual studio 2017?
I saw that I can add packages with the NPM, but it only adds the js versions of the packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install typescript version of package like this : `npm install -S @types/lodash`

FOund this here : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html

I tried it with package like express and it works pretty well.

Comment: how can i do it with vs2017?

Comment: if i remember well you can use vs2017's terminal